# php syntax: program flow control using the || operator

Tags: php, syntax, control-flow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP short circuit lazy evaluation, where is it in the php.net manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220919/php-short-circuit-lazy-evaluation-where-is-it-in-the-php-net-manual)
>   [PHP “or” Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535255/php-or-syntax)

I have seen people using the `||` operator as program flow control as follows:

```
function() || die("message");
```

where `die("message");` will run if `function()` returns `false`. Furthermore, it seems to only work for `die();` and `exit();` else the interpreter will throw a "syntax error" message.

I'm wondering what this is called and where can I find documentation for its behaviour.

Comment: You should have no problem using this for any function. This just a simple boolean OR.

Comment: For reference the first time I saw it was in a mysql database connection script where they have `mysql_select_db($database, $connection) || die(mysql_error()) ;`

Comment: It's a rather confusing "clever trick". I'd avoid it for the sake of maintainability.

Comment: @John You could easily define your own functions and do `foo() || bar()`. There's no special treatment of `exit` or `die`.

Comment: It does not only work for `die` and `exit`. It works for *expressions* (where function calls are one option). Commonly `or` is preferred over `||` however.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Don't use [`or die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) when outputting HTML. You'll get invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a boolean OR expression.  The usage is taking advantage of a behavior called short cutting, where if the first part of the expression evaluates to `true`, then the second half isn't evaluated because the OR expression is already `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just logic OR. If `function()` returns `true`, then the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Ah I get it now, it didn't occur to me that shortcircuit evaluations work outside of control expressions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `OR` / `||` being an operator with left precedence (see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as the left is evaluated to be true, there is no point in evaluating the right side as the expression will always be true.